# Setting up multiple log directories in Stripe

Tags: laravel

I have my logging set up like this in Laravel:

```
'default' => env('LOG_CHANNEL', 'stack'),

'stack' => [
        'driver' => 'stack',
        'channels' => ['daily'],
        'ignore_exceptions' => false,
    ],

    'single' => [
        'driver' => 'single',
        'path' => storage_path('logs/laravel.log'),
        'level' => 'debug',
    ],

    'daily' => [
        'driver' => 'daily',
        'path' => storage_path('logs/laravel.log'),
        'level' => 'debug',
        'days' => 14,
        'permission' => 0666,
    ],
```

This creates logs for each day in `storage/logs`.

Now, what I want to do, is send only the log messages from my scheduled tasks to a separate log directory altogether. For example, to `storage/logs/cron`. But I want to keep the other messages in the current setup.

How do I make this happen? I've tried creating a new channel in config but it still logs the messages in the same files.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new channel in `config/logging.php`. Ie:

```
'cronjob' => [
    'driver' => 'single',
    'path' => storage_path('logs/cronjob.log'),
    'level' => 'debug',
],
```

And then you can use it in your command (or anywhere) adding the `channel` method:

```
Log::channel('cronjob')->info('Command started. ');
```

If you want to log exceptions use a `try/catch`:

```
try {
    // ...
} catch (\Exception $exception) {
    Log::channel('cronjob')->error($exception);
}
```